# Best way to store massive number of sessions in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, memcached

We have recently built a website for a client who is now seeing a ton of traffic, specifically they have sources where when they promote the site we see around 400-600k records stored in our database under "sessions"

The sessions table in database is no longer a viable method for us to store so many sessions as it is creating a lot of performance issues.

We have recently moved to files, but that also is causing it's own problems (such as accessing the folder etc)

Has anyone had experience in this and can we get a recommendation on what to move to? memcached maybe?

Comment: Do you actually clear / clean up your sessions?

Comment: @JonStirling hahhha Well I am guessing not, unless they actually have 400,000 users active at one time. That of course would probably cause other more interesting issues

Comment: Of course we do; however it still does not make sense to really put load on database when there are so many users on the site. They get approximately 120K unique visitors a day.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Exactly ;)

Comment: But unique visitors per day does not equate to active sessions

Comment: Would you recommend moving to cookies and keeping sessions alive only for that actual "session"?

Comment: So how often does your app clear old sessions from the database? And how long do you consider a session still active after its last timestamp

Comment: what are you storing in your `sessions` that they need to be active for every visitor?

Comment: also straight from `codeigniter` docs "Some of you will probably opt to choose another session driver because file storage is usually slower. This is only half true.

A very basic test will probably trick you into believing that an SQL database is faster, but in 99% of the cases, this is only true while you only have a few current sessions. As the sessions count and server loads increase - which is the time when it matters - the file system will consistently outperform almost all relational database setups.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver

Comment: If you have moved to session files the question still stands _So how often does your app clear old sessions? And how long do you consider a session still active after its use_ i.e. what are you setting in `php.ini`

Comment: A session has a lifespan of 6 hours, after 6 hours of inactivity we clear them.

Comment: And whats the average duration of a visit to this site, maybe you should cut the 6 hours down by a bit, or more than a bit

Comment: Thanks guys, I think the best way to do it is cut it down and should the client want to have it for longer move to cookie + session combo.

Comment: Unless you're holding session IDs in the URL, then you're probably already using a "cookie + session" combo. Even if you aren't, I'm not sure how you expect it to make a difference to the amount of sessions you're storing based on ttl.

Comment: An expired session cookie or closed session does not mean the session file (or DB record) will be immediately deleted. How often garbage is collected depends on php.ini settings. In particular the `session.gc_divisor` has a major impact. With `session.gc_divisor = 100` there is a 1% chance the gc will run on any given session initialization. A value of 100 is usually pretty good and a recommended value for a production server. But many times I've found it to be set at 1000 which means there is a 0.1% chance of gc. A lot of garbage will collect in that case.

Comment: BTW, I am fairly certain that CodeIgniter sessions use and require cookies.

Comment: hi - if you want more help post this on forum.codeigniter.com